# Can I legally reuse fields in aggregate struct initialization?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

The program below compiles and runs without warnings with gcc:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A { int a, b; };
int main() {
  A x = {.a = 42, .b = x.a}; // <-- b is initialized from x.a
  std::cout << x.a << ' ' << x.b << std::endl;
}
```

> 42 42

`x` is essentially used during its initialization. This is very handy for cases where `.a` is initialized by a large expression.

Is this a legal expression in C++, and am I guaranteed to always get the right answer?

Comment: AFAIK designated initializers are new in C++20 so your [tag:c++17] tag seems inapplicable.

Comment: I think it would work, as *the members of the current object are initialized in their natural order, unless designators are used,* which I assume means unless the designators change the order. So in your case, as long as `.a = 42` happens first, then `.b = x.a` it's fine.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm not sure what changes are happening in C++20, but designated initializers exist before C++20 for backwards compatibility with C99. I'll remove C++17 and add C tag to see if I can get some input from the C community

Comment: I don't see anything expressly forbidding it and the hard rules about ordering in designated initializers should make it hard to accidentally assign `.a` from `.b`.

Comment: @user4581301 interestingly, `A x = {.a = x.b, .b = 42};` compiles and actually works... hm.

Comment: I think you guys are right. I tried initializing `.b` using `.a` and I got the error "designator order for field ‘A::a’ does not match declaration order in ‘A’". It looks like something the compiler team have thought about, so if it was UB they would have disallowed it

Comment: *if it was UB they would have disallowed it*.... not sure I'd assume that, in general. :)

Comment: @lurker If you do `A x = {.b = 5, .a = x.b};` you get an error. That's super weird. Note `A x = {.b = 5, .a = 5};` compiles fine.

Comment: @Kostas: C++ didn't have designated initializers until C++20, though several _compilers_ allowed it before then anyway.

Comment: Kostas: "_If you do `A x = {.b = 5, .a = x.b};` you get an error._" - That's an error in C++, not in C. (comment made when there was both a C and C++ tag)

Comment: @lurker My worries are with the messiness you get in the member initializer list where you can place b in the list ahead of a but the initialization order is unchanged, often without warning. People think they set b and then assigned it to a, but.... nope. Since C++20  spits out an error if you place b ahead of a in an aggregate initializer, this bug is harder to fall into. But not impossible as you point out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [dcl.init.aggr]
>
> The initializations of the elements of the aggregate are evaluated in the element order.
> That is, all value computations and side effects associated with a given element are sequenced before those of any element that follows it in order.

Thus, `x.a` has been initialised before initialisation of `x.b`. So far, so good.

> [basic.life]
>
> The lifetime of an object or reference is a runtime property of the object or reference. A variable is said to have vacuous initialization if it is default-initialized and, if it is of class type or a (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, that class type has a trivial default constructor. The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
> - its initialization (if any) is complete (including vacuous initialization) ([dcl.init]),

The lifetime of `x.a` has begun although the lifetime of `x` has not.

---

> Similarly, before the lifetime of an object has started ... any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways.
> For an object under construction or destruction, see [class.cdtor].
> Otherwise, such a glvalue refers to allocated storage ([basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]), and using the properties of the glvalue that do not depend on its value is well-defined.
> The program has undefined behavior if:
>
> - the glvalue is used to access the object, or
> - ...

"Access" is defined:

> [defns.access]
>
> ⟨execution-time action⟩ read or modify the value of an object
>
> Note 1: Only objects of scalar type can be accessed.
> Reads of scalar objects are described in [conv.lval] and modifications of scalar objects are describred in [expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], and [expr.pre.incr].
> Attempts to read or modify an object of class type typically invoke a constructor or assignment operator; such invocations do not themselves constitute accesses, although they may involve accesses of scalar subobjects.
> — end note]

According to this *note*, accessing `x.a` is not an access of the class object named by `x`. Thus, `x.a` being initialised should be sufficient and the example is well-defined and OK.

Minor problem: Notes are not normative.

---

Edit: I removed quotes to rules that apply to objects "under/during construction" with the assumption that those do not apply to aggregates being initialised.

---

P.S. Perhaps for clarity, or even just to not make readers of the code to be concerned about the legality, consider using an intermediate variable:

```
int temp = 42;
A x = {.a = temp, .b = temp};
```

P.P.S Designated initialisers were first introduced to standard C++ in C++20. They are not in C+17.

Comment: [class.cdtor] apply to period during constructor (and destructor) invocation, but in aggregate initialization there is none.

Comment: @eerorika: It's the part that says "during construction". That means "during a constructor". If they meant it for all objects, it would be "during initialization".

Comment: @LanguageLawyer @ NicolBolas Fair enough.

Comment: _This is a bit tricky, since the glvalue `x` is used to access `x`_ In C++, there can't be access to an object of non-scalar type. BTW, compare [basic.life]/(6.2) to /(7.2).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Fair enough again. Then I see no problem with the example.

Comment: BTW, it is not guaranteed that my first comment is 100% correct.

Comment: This is by far the best answer I've ever gotten on stack overflow. I really appreciate your time and and I'm slightly in awe about how you connected all these points so quickly.